# How to pass Flatlist items to another screens Flatlist?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How do I pass FlatList items to another screen that also have a FlatList?

I'm using React Navigation V5 to pass the FlatList item to the other screen. Thats working fine. I can see the text when only using ´<Text.>{details.id}</Text .>´ but not when trying to pass it to FlatList, then there is nothing.

CODE

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  TextInput,
  FlatList,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Linking,
  Modal,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';
import { useTheme } from '../Data/ThemeContext';
import DataBase from '../Data/DataBase';

import Octicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Octicons';

export default function Home({ navigation }) {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [masterDataSource, setMasterDataSource] = useState(DataBase);
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [details, setDetails] = useState('');

  const { colors } = useTheme();

  const filteredDataSource = masterDataSource.filter((item) => {
    return (
      item.name.includes(search) ||
      (item.id && item.id.includes(search)) ||
      (item.gluten && item.gluten.includes(search)) ||
      (item.company && item.company.includes(search))
    );
  });

  const itemSeparatorComponent = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          margin: 3,
        }}></View>
    );
  };

  const emptyComponent = () => {
    return (
      <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={{ color: colors.text }}>Finns inte produkten med?</Text>
        <View style={{ marginTop: 30 }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => Linking.openURL('')}>
            <Text
              style={{
                color: colors.text,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: colors.text,
                padding: 10,
                borderRadius: 5,
                backgroundColor: colors.card,
              }}>
              KONTAKTA OSS
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            marginLeft: 20,
            marginRight: 20,
            elevation: 3,
            backgroundColor: colors.card,
            borderRadius: 10,
          }}
          onPress={() => {
            setModalVisible(true);
            setDetails(item);
          }}>
          <View style={{ margin: 10 }}>
            <Text style={{ color: colors.text }}>{item.company}</Text>
            <Text style={{ color: colors.text, fontWeight: '700' }}>
              {item.name}
            </Text>
            <Text style={{ color: colors.text }}>{item.gluten}</Text>
            <Text style={{ color: colors.text }}>{item.id}</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: colors.background }}>
      <Modal
        animationType="none"
        hardwareAccelerated={true}
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
        }}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)',
          }}>
          <View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: colors.Modal,
              padding: 35,
              borderRadius: 10,
              width: '80%',
              height: '80%',
            }}>
            <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
              <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
                <Text style={{ color: colors.text }}>{details.company}</Text>
                <Text
                  style={{ color: colors.text, marginTop: 20, fontSize: 20 }}>
                  {details.name}
                </Text>
                <Text style={{ color: colors.text, marginTop: 20 }}>
                  {details.gluten}
                </Text>
                <Text style={{ color: colors.text, marginTop: 20 }}>
                  Ingredienser
                </Text>
                <Text style={{ color: colors.text, marginTop: 2 }}>
                  {details.ingredients}
                </Text>
                <Text style={{ color: colors.text, marginTop: 30 }}>
                  {details.id}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </ScrollView>
            <View
              style={{
                borderTopWidth: 1,
                borderTopColor: colors.text,
                marginBottom: 10,
              }}></View>
            <View
              style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-evenly' }}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  const updated = [...masterDataSource];
                  updated.find(
                    (item) => item.id === details.id,
                  ).selected = true;
                  setMasterDataSource(updated);
                  navigation.navigate('Inköpslista', {
                    items: updated.filter((item) => item.selected),
                  });
                }}>
                <Text>Lägg i Inköpslistan</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  setModalVisible(false);
                }}>
                <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'center', color: '#FF0000' }}>
                  Stäng
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          padding: 20,
          backgroundColor: colors.Textinput,
          elevation: 12,
        }}>
        <TextInput
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            borderTopLeftRadius: 5,
            borderBottomLeftRadius: 5,
          }}
          placeholder=" SÖK PRODUKT NAMN / STRECKKOD"
          placeholderTextColor="#000"
          onChangeText={(text) => setSearch(text)}
          value={search}
          autoCapitalize="words"
        />
        <Octicons
          style={{
            marginLeft: 1,
            padding: 13,
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            height: 49,
            borderTopRightRadius: 5,
            borderBottomRightRadius: 5,
          }}
          name="checklist"
          size={25}
          color="#000"
          onPress={() =>
            navigation.navigate('Inköpslista', {
              items: masterDataSource.filter((item) => item.selected),
            })
          }
        />
      </View>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 20 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={filteredDataSource}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={itemSeparatorComponent}
          keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          initialNumToRender={4}
          maxToRenderPerBatch={5}
          windowSize={10}
          removeClippedSubviews={true}
          updateCellsBatchingPeriod={100}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
          ListEmptyComponent={emptyComponent}
          contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 20 }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

SECOND SCREEN

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function ShoppingList({ route, navigation }) {
  const RenderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ marginHorizontal: 10, marginVertical: 15 }}
        onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text>{item.id}</Text>
        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        marginTop: 30,
      }}>
      <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
      <FlatList
        data={route.params && route.params.items}
        renderItem={RenderItem}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: That's because you are setting your state to `empty` after modal close...and Also on which button/text you click to open Modal??

Comment: @KartikeyVaish added more code above^^

Comment: I am unable to understand the flow.
can you post a minimum working code with all constant values and import statements? that can be run just by copy-pasting to vs code?
expo snack would be great?

Comment: @MRPMOHIBURRAHMAN I have edited the code above with full code.

Comment: @Lmao12233 you only have the home component here, can you tell us what you are trying to do ?, like you move from home screen to another screen etc ?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan I'm trying to add flatlist items from screen 1 to 2nd screen. Example buying things on the internet => once you hit buy, that item gets added to the cart. My "cart" is on the 2nd screen

Comment: ok from what I understand, you have two screens the first screen has a flatlist and once you click you open a modal and pass the item to the next screen, whats the issue here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, this is the flow that you want

1. User has flat list with a set of items
2. When an item is clicked a modal is opened
3. If the user wants he clicks 'Add to cart' which will add item to cart and open cart.
4. When cart is opened user is shown a flatlist with the selected items.

Screen 1 : Home

Here you already have a modal but you pass a single item instead of an array.

So the better way is to use the masterDataSource state that you have and add a 'selected' property to it.

So the button in the Modal would be like this

```
        <Button
          title="Add and View Cart"
          onPress={() => {
            const updated = [...masterDataSource];
            updated.find((item) => item.id === details.id).selected = true;
            setMasterDataSource(updated);
            navigation.navigate('Cart', {
              items: updated.filter((item) => item.selected),
            });
          }}
        />
```

Once you click the Button you would be taken to the cart page with the items array which you have selected (This will have the previous items as well).

The Cart screen will have a Flatlist to show the items that are passed via params like below. RenderItem can be the code for your item.

```
  <FlatList
    data={route.params && route.params.items}
    renderItem={RenderItem}
  />
```

You can run the sample below

https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/cartexample

(Modal doesnt work properly on web you can try the android version)

Comment: Seems like my text when going to the other screen doesnt show. Ive done exactly like the expo snack

Comment: are you passing a single item like in your question or an array like the code in the snack ?

Comment: @Lmao12233 any way i can see the second screen code ?

Comment: right now its just a copy paste from ur expo snack. I updated the code above^^

Comment: you are still passing the details which is an object navigation.navigate('Inköpslista', {
                    details,
                  }) check the way I have passed in the snack I have passed the array of items that are selected

Comment: no i have done exactly like in ur expo snack. But i have now updated the home screen code above^^ i had only updated the second screen before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231944/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-lmao12233).

Answer (score 0):

According to React Native [Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.63/flatlist#data), the prop  `data` on FlatList should contain an **Array**, like this `[{...}]` or this `[{...},{...},{...}...]`. But you are trying to pass an **Object** to the FlatList on the ShoppingList screen, like this `{...}`.

On ShoppingList Screen when you're destructuring like the following

```
const { details } = route.params;
```

You are creating an object, which looks like this `{...}`
So you need to convert it to an array. Use the following code snippet

```
const itemInfo = []
itemInfo.push(details)
```

Now just pass `itemInfo` to `data` prop of `FlatList`.

Your ShoppingList screen should look like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    View,
    FlatList,
    Text,
  } from 'react-native';
  
  export default function ShoppingList({ route }) {
    
    const { details } = route.params;
    const itemInfo = [];
    itemInfo.push(details);
    
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "white" }}>
        <FlatList
          data={itemInfo}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <View>
                <Text style={{ color: "black" }}>{item.company}</Text>
                <Text style={{ color: "black" }}>{item.name}</Text>
                <Text style={{ color: "black" }}>{item.gluten}</Text>
                <Text style={{ color: "black" }}>{item.id}</Text>
              </View>
            )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: It's complaining about `cannot read property 'details' of undefined` I did get this error before also

Comment: @Lmao12233, please, take a look at the GitHub repo and compare it to your source code.

Comment: @Lmao12233, I didn't get that error on my project ( look at that GitHub repo )

Comment: I looked at the github but even if the code is the same i still get the `cannot read property 'details' of underfined`  I also made a new project trying this and there i didnt even get an error

Comment: @Lmao12233, in that case, I need to take look at your project. You can delete all the confidential and unnecessary part that are not related to this question and upload that to GitHub. and send me the link here.

Comment: The problem is solved. if you wouldnt mind deleteing the github page. Thanks for the help tho.